# New error being thrown after upgrade to 8.2

Tags: xdb

I had a method which worked fine in 8.0 but now is throwing an error in 8.2 Update 2.

The method is:

```
public bool AddPageEvent(Guid DefinitionId, Guid PageEventItemId, string PageEventName, string PageEventData, string PageEventText) {
    try
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(Tracker.Current, "Tracker.Current");
        Assert.IsNotNull(Tracker.Current.Session, "Tracker.Current.Session");
        var interaction = Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction;
        Assert.IsNotNull(interaction, "Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction");
        Assert.IsNotNull(interaction.CurrentPage, "Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.CurrentPage");
        var pageEventData = new PageEventData(PageEventName, DefinitionId)
        {
            ItemId = PageEventItemId,
            Data = PageEventData,
            Text = PageEventText
        };
        interaction.CurrentPage.Register(pageEventData);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("MySite.Analytics.PageEvents.AddPageEvent", ex, this);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The following error is being thrown on the first `Assert.IsNotNull` :

> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException Message: Tracker.Current
>   Source: MySite.Analytics    at MySite.Analytics.PageEvents.AddPageEvent(Guid
>   DefinitionId, Guid PageEventItemId, String PageEventName, String
>   PageEventData, String PageEventText) in
>   C:\SRC\Main\Sitecore\MySite.Analytics\PageEvents.cs:line 27

Any ideas why this would throw this error in 8.2?

Comment: Do you have Analytics enabled?

Comment: Yeah, but only on one node so far (just working out some config issues).   I'm wondering if it is a session issue?

Comment: @Diego, when you are using xDB Cloud 2.0 the `Analytics.Enabled` setting should be **false**, and the `Xdb.Enabled` setting should be **true**, correct?

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: @Artsem Working through a couple other issues with Sitecore Support now, so can't be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I'va got the same issue. I've fixed that with the following code. Thy this:

```
public bool AddPageEvent(Guid DefinitionId, Guid PageEventItemId, string PageEventName, string PageEventData, string PageEventText)
    {
        try
        {
            //check id tracker is active. start it if it is not.
            if (!Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.IsActive)
            {
                Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.StartTracking();
            }

            //ensure that tracker has a CurrentPage and already activated
            if (Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.IsActive && Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.CurrentPage != null)
            {                    
                if (PageEventItemId != Guid.Empty) {

                    var pageEventData = new Sitecore.Analytics.Data.PageEventData(PageEventName)
                    {
                        ItemId = PageEventItemId,
                        Data = PageEventData,
                        Text = PageEventText
                    };

                    var pageEventsRow = Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.Register(pageEventData);                         
                    Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Interaction.AcceptModifications(); 
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("MySite.Analytics.PageEvents.AddPageEvent", ex, this);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It can happen when the Tracker is not active. So you need the following check and start the Tracking if it is not active.

```
if (!Tracker.IsActive)
{
    Tracker.StartTracking();
}
```

Also a good practice the check the Tracker is enabled or not. Before start tracking you can check it:

```
if (!Tracker.Enabled)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I have never found the tracker to not be on. Wouldn't that be a sign of a deeper issue?

Comment: @dnstommy I experienced this, when a page does not use any Sitecore Tracking feature like a Goal or Profiling, then `Tracker.IsActive` is false. So it only happens when you want to use Tracking from custom code first time in the session.